# What is the most idiomatic way to perform multiple tests in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have the following logic:

```
some_array.each do |element|
  if element[:apples] == another_hash[:apples] &&
    element[:oranges] == another_hash[:oranges] &&
    element[:pineapple] == another_hash[:pineapple]
      match = element
     break
  end
end
```

I iterate through a list of key value pairs. If I can match the required keys (3 of 5), then I toss the element in a var for later use. If I find a match, I break out of the loop.

I am looking for the most idiomatic way to optimize this conditional. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
match = some_array.find do |element|
  [:apples, :oranges, :pinapple].all? {|key| element[key] == another_hash[key]}
end
```

If you want to select any element which has at least 3 matching keys from 5 keys given then:

```
match = some_array.find do |element|
  element.keys.select {|key| element[key| == another_hash[key]}.size > 2
end
```

Comment: Freakin awesome. Much better than before. Thank you!

Comment: For my example, with `fruit = [:apple, :plum]` you return `{:apple=>6, :cherry=>2, :pineapple=>8, :fig=>3}`, but `another_hash` does not have a key `:plum`, so it should return `nil`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Both hashes has no `:plum`, so it works as expected I believe? :)

Comment: I was going by "required keys", and assumed the OP's code was slightly in error, but your code is consistent with your interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'd do it.

**Code**

```
def fruit_match(some_array, another_hash, fruit)
  other_vals = another_hash.values_at(*fruit)
  return nil if other_vals.include?(nil)
  some_array.find { |h| h.values_at(*fruit) == other_vals }
end
```

**Examples**

```
some_array = [ { apple: 1, orange: 2, pineapple: 3, plum: 4 },
               { apple: 1, cherry: 7, pineapple: 6, plum: 2 },
               { apple: 6, cherry: 2, pineapple: 8, fig:  3 } ]

another_hash = { apple: 6, cherry: 4, pineapple: 8, quamquat: 5 }

fruit = [:apple, :pineapple]
fruit_match(some_array, another_hash, fruit)
  #=> { :apple=>6, :cherry=>2, :pineapple=>8, :fig=>3 }

fruit = [:apple, :plum]
fruit_match(some_array, another_hash, fruit)
  #=> nil
```

**[Edit:** I didn't notice the "3-5" matches until I saw @7stud's answer. Requiring the number of matches to fall within a given range is an interesting variation. Here's how I would address that requirement.

**Code**

```
def fruit_match(some_array, another_hash, fruit, limits)
  other_vals = another_hash.values_at(*fruit)
  some_array.select { |h| limits.cover?(h.values_at(*fruit)
                                .zip(other_vals)
                                .count {|e,o| e==o && e}) }
end
```

**Example**

```
some_array = [ { apple: 1, orange: 2, pineapple: 1, cherry: 1 },
               { apple: 2, cherry: 7, pineapple: 6, plum: 2 },
               { apple: 6, cherry: 1, pineapple: 8, fig:  3 },
               { apple: 1, banana: 2, pineapple: 1, fig:  3 } ]

another_hash = { apple: 1, cherry: 1, pineapple: 1, quamquat: 1 }
fruit = [:apple, :pineapple, :cherry]
limits = (1..2)

fruit_match(some_array, another_hash, fruit, limits)
  #=> [{:apple=>6, :cherry=>1, :pineapple=>8, :fig=>3},
  #    {:apple=>1, :banana=>2, :pineapple=>1, :fig=>3}]
```

**tidE]**

Comment: You used `#values_at`.. I was trying to give the same solution.. I wouldn't now.. +1.. :-)

Comment: Thank you Cary for the feedback. This is also a valid solution to me. I have use cases for all three answers here, so this is definitely most helpful. Thank you!

Comment: **just replace find with select**  I don't see how that would work.

Answer (score 1):

More readable version I could think is `slice`:

```
keys = [:apples, :oranges, :pinapple]
match = some_array.find {|e| e.slice( *keys ) == another_hash.slice( *keys )}
```

**UPDATE**

Slice is not a pure ruby method of Hash, it includes in Rails' ActiveSupport library.

If you don't want to be using Rails, you can just load Active Support.

Add active_support to your Gemfile and `require "active_support/core_ext/hash/slice"`.

Or you could just paste the contents of slice.rb into your app somewhere. The URL can be found [here](https://github.com/lifo/docrails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/slice.rb).

Comment: This looks like a great solution as well. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Cat, did you mean `values_at` where you have `slice`?  Neither Hash` nor `Enumerable` has a `slice` method.  With `values_at`, that's almost what I have, except for a line to deal with the problem I mentioned in a comment on @BroiSatse's solution.

Answer (score 1):

> If I can match the required keys (3 of 5)

I don't think any of the posted answers addresses that.

```
target_keys = %i[
  apples
  oranges
  pineapples
  strawberries
  bananas
]

data = [
  {beer: 0, apples: 1, oranges: 2, pineapples: 3, strawberries: 4, bananas: 5},
  {beer: 1, apples: 6, oranges: 7, pineapples: 8, strawberries: 9, bananas: 10},
  {beer: 2, apples: 6, oranges: 2, pineapples: 3, strawberries: 9, bananas: 10},
]

match_hash = {
  apples: 6, oranges: 2, pineapples: 3, strawberries: 9, bananas: 10
}

required_matches = 3
required_values = match_hash.values_at(*target_keys).to_enum
found_match = nil

catch :done do

  data.each do |hash|
    found_values = hash.values_at(*target_keys).to_enum
    match_count = 0

    loop do
      match_count += 1 if found_values.next == required_values.next

      if match_count == required_matches
        found_match = hash
        throw :done
      end
    end

    required_values.rewind
  end

end

p found_match

--output:--
{:beer=>1, :apples=>6, :oranges=>7, :pineapple=>8, :strawberry=>9, :banana=>10
```

Comment: Thank you 7stud. This answer has also given me some ideas. I appreciate you for taking the time.

Comment: @user2152283, I revised my answer a bit.